# How to remove duplicate array of object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
const words = [{value:"can_view",rolename:"group"},
{value:"can_create",rolename:"group"},
```

{value:"can_create",rolename:"top"}];
    {value:"can_delete",rolename:"group"}];

```
{value:"can_delete",rolename:"top"}];
```

I am trying to get value from array of objects. I want to get value this format

```
        Accepted Value: {
         group:["can_view","can_create"],
         top:["can_delete"]
        }
```

And also I want to remove array of string based on rolename from output..forexample, "can_create",can_delete remove only from group property.
Here is my codesanbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-http-v35lf

Comment: In your example there are no duplicates

Comment: Please be clearer, show the input an the expected output

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `Array#reduce`

```js
const words = [{value:"can_view",rolename:"group"},{value:"can_create",rolename:"group"},{value:"can_delete",rolename:"top"}];

const res =  words.reduce((acc,{rolename,value})=>{
   acc[rolename] = acc[rolename] || [];
   acc[rolename].push(value);
   return acc
},{});


console.log(res)
```

Comment: if user want to remove array of string from "group": [
    "can_view",
    "can_create"
  ]  by using onclick event , How can i do this?

Comment: please post your html and click event with in fiddle and also you expect result i will change

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-http-v35lf I am giving you codesanbox link, I am using react

Comment: you code looks ok .but still not clear with your question.can you elaborate little bit more

Comment: users click on checkbox ,each checkbox will be give value such as can_view ,can_create based on rolename and user can  remove can_view, can_create click on checkbox

Comment: you mean unchecked to remove the value from array right?

Comment: yes , I want to remove unchecked value , but value will be removed based on rolename.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop to get this done. You need to group by **rolename** here.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2

```js
 const words = [
  { value: "can_view", rolename: "group" },
  { value: "can_create", rolename: "group" },
  { value: "can_delete", rolename: "top" },
  { value: "can_delete", rolename: "group" }
];

const result = {};
for (const { value, rolename } of words) {
  if (!result[rolename]) result[rolename] = [];
  result[rolename].push(value);
}

function removeElement(obj, arr) {
 for (var key of Object.keys(result)) {
    if (key === obj) {
      result[key] = result[key].filter(i => !arr.includes(i));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const modified = removeElement("group", ["can_delete"]);
console.log(modified);
```

Comment: if user want to remove array of string from "group": [ "can_view", "can_create" ] by using onclick event after creating this format , How can i do this? I mean when user click event - group:["can_view"]

Comment: array of strings? an example please

Comment: Here is Output : {
  "group": [
    "can_view",
    "can_create"
  ],
  "top": [
    "can_delete"
  ]
} , but I want to delete can_view, can_create and can_create based on rolename and add new value can_create Accepeted Value:{
  "group": [],
  "top": [
    "can_delete","can_create"
  ]
} ,

Comment: [{top:"can_create",group:"can_create}] I just want to remove can_create from top, not all of other objects .

Comment: may be try something on your own, I can guide you in case you go wrong somewhere

Comment: have added the edit . inside loop compare the key that you want to match and then go forward with removing the items.

Comment: I actually want to remove item based on rolename  https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-http-v35lf

Comment: please raise a new question. you are adding new cases every now and then. The recent edit which I posted above , is based on role name itself. "group" or "top" are the role names right?

Comment: thats what I am doing, https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2